# Set a div element always at the bottom of the QWEB report, not "footer"

Tags: odoo, report, qweb, odoo-16

I would like to fix a div element to be always at the bottom of the QWEB report, I do not want to put it in the "footer" as it will show on every page.

Currently, I'm using a temporary solution

```
<div style="position: absolute; top:650px; width:100%;page-break-inside: avoid;">
    ​<div> CONTENT
    ​</div>
</div>
```

However, I face an issue where if the above content is long, then I would get overlapped problem